# How can I determine if this decomposition of $K_{33,33}$ comes from an alpha-labelling?

Tags: graph-theory

The graph depicted below, when cyclically rotated, gives a decomposition of $K_{33,33}$.  It has $22$ vertices, $33$ edges, and is $3$-regular (i.e., cubic).  It was found by my computer.

[image: a $22$-vertex, $33$-edge, cubic graph which gives a decomposition of $K_{33,33}$]

We can verify the decomposition claim by checking that each edge length occurs exactly once.  It is therefore possible that this decomposition is equivalent to an alpha-labelling (perhaps by multiplying the indices by a number coprime to $33$ and/or adding a constant).

**Question**: How can I determine if this decomposition of $K_{33,33}$ comes from an alpha-labelling?

And, of course, I'm not just interested in this particular graph, but being able to solve instances of this problem in general.

---

Definition:

An alpha-labelling is a labelling $f$ of the vertices of an $n$-edge graph with distinct labels from $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ such that (a) if each edge $xy$ is assigned the label $|f(x)-f(y)|$, the resulting edge labels are distinct, and (b) there exists an integer $k$ so that for each edge $xy$ either $f(x) \leq k < f(y)$ or $f(y) \leq k < f(x)$.  For example:

[image: alpha labelling of a graph]

(with $k=6$; example "borrowed" from Pasotti, [Constructions for cyclic Moebius ladder systems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2009.03.050), Disc. Math., 2010).

They give rise to decompositions of $K_{n,n}$.  The above example gives rise to:

[image: decomposition of $K_{20,20}$]

(for each of the $n$ edges, big indices ($> k$) go up the top, and small indices ($\leq k$) down the bottom; taken modulo $n$) which gives a decomposition of $K_{21,21}$ if cycled.

(El-Zanati and Eynden, [Decompositions of $K_{m,n}$ into cubes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1520-6610(1996)4:1%3C51::AID-JCD5%3E3.0.CO;2-Z), J. Combin. Des., 1996)